# Kubernetes Volume, PersistentVolume, PersistentVolumeClaim

Tags: kubernetes

I've been working with Kubernetes for quite a while, but still often got confused about Volume, PersistentVolume and PersistemtVolumeClaim. It would be nice if someone could briefly summarize the difference of them.

Comment: As the tag says, "KUBERNETES QUESTIONS MUST BE DEVELOPER RELATED." Meaning they must be related to a programming issue and not an operating system one.

Comment: These are technical terms in Kubernetes, but there's pretty extensive official documentation on both [Volumes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/) and [Persistent Volumes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Volume - For a pod to reference a storage that is external , it needs volume spec. This volume can be from configmap, from secrets, from persistantvolumeclaim, from hostpath etc

PeristentVolume - It is representation of a storage that is made avaliable. The plugins for cloud provider enable to create this resource.

PeristentVolumeClaim - This claims specific resources and if the persistent volume is avaliable in namespaces match the claim requirement, then claim get tied to that Peristentvolume

At this point this PVC/PV aren't used. Then in Pod spec, pod makes use of claim as volumes and then the storage is attached to Pod

Answer (score 0):

These are all in a Kubernetes application context. Too keep applications portable between different Kubernetes platforms, it is good to abstract away the infrastructure from the application. Here I will explain the Kubernetes objects that belongs to **Application config** and also to the **Platform config**. If your application runs on both e.g. GCP and AWS, you will need two sets of *platform configs*, one for GCP and one for AWS.

## Application config

### Volume

A pod may mount volumes. The source for volumes can be different things, e.g. a ConfigMap, Secret or a **PersistentVolumeClaim**

### PersistentVolumeClaim

A PersistentVolumeClaim represents a claim of a specific PersistentVolume instance. For portability this claim can be for a specific **StorageClass**, e.g. SSD.

## Platform config

### StorageClass

A StorageClass represents PersistentVolume **type** with specific properties. It can be e.g. SSD. But the StorageClass is different on each platform, e.g. one definition on AWS, Azure, another on GCP or on Minikube.

### PersistentVolume

This is a specific volume on the platform. And it may be different on platforms, e.g. awsElasticBlockStore or gcePersistentDisk. This is the instance that holds the actual data.

## Minikube example

See [Configure a Pod to Use a PersistentVolume for Storage](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-persistent-volume-storage/) for a full example on how to use **PersistentVolume**, **StorageClass** and **Volume** for a Pod using Minikube and a *hostPath*.